# AngularJs: I want to destroy the content in Modal Popup on Button Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to destroy the content in a modal pop up on button click so that on opening the pop up again, no content is found. So I have this

```
//clear the content of the text field
   $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

This is the button that calls the function

```
<button style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px; color: #ff6000" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="cancel()">Clear</button>
```

This is the content in the modal pop up

```
<label class="item item-input">
              <textarea ng-model="content" rows="5" placeholder="What's new..."></textarea>
          </label>
<img id="myImage" ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" class="imgBorder full-image">
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens. Please what is the cuase.

EDITED:
This is the code block that opens the modal

```
// Open our new task modal
  $scope.newPost = function(index) {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});
       if (index == 1) $scope.postModal.show()
      else $scope.selectModal.show();
     // $scope.postModal.show();

  };
```

Comment: Have you crosschecked with the documentation? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal Hint: take a look into the Plunker for more details.

Comment: where is content variable?
just use $scope.text = 'foo bar';
and in view -> {{ text }}

when you want to empty text -> $scope.text = '';

Comment: just $scope.content = ''; 
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    $scope.content = ''; 
  };

Comment: @Kollley, had tried this solution earlier on. On clicking the button <button style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px; color: #ff6000" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="cancel()">Clear</button> nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you destroy the modalInstance in the code that initially creates it via its $destroy() function, the next time the creation code is run it will start over again.

For **AngularUI**, this could look like:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});

modalInstance
    .result
    .then( function( modalResult ){
        // Do something with modal result if you want
    }).finally(function(){
        modalInstance.$destroy(); 
        // After calling this, the next time open is called, everything will be re-initialized.
    });
```

Built out an example in plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/KUDSFc

For **Ionic**, I would approach the issue a bit differently. It looks like a case of problematic scope inheritance. Ionic modal scopes inherit the scope of their initializing controller (when passed in during `fromTemplateUrl()`). When you bind ng-models directly to primitives on scope, they break interitance. Google the "ngModel dot rule" for more detail - or for a TON of detail, check out the angular wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

What it boils down to, is always have a "dot" when you bind to ng-model. Otherwise child scopes will make a copy of inherited primitives instead of updating their parent scope's variable.

So, for your case add one more layer on the parent scope before binding to `.content`.

Example:

```
angular.controller( 'TestCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ){
    $scope.data = {
        content: '' // This is what we'll bind the modal's textarea to
    };

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl( 'my-modal.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    } ).then( function( postModal ) {
        $scope.postModal = postModal;
    });

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
        var content = $scope.data.content; // Make a copy of whatever was entered on the modal and do what you want with it
        $scope.data.content = ''; // Clear out the ng-modal content
        $scope.postModal.hide(); // Hide the modal
    };
}]);
```

Working sample I wrote on the Ionic playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/a33e2f54ec0a

(Helpful info taken from the Ionic docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/ and http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/ )

Comment: Tried the solution, but no head way. Is there a means I can force the value in the textarea to "" on closing the modal. Because I have tried several approaches

Comment: I suppose you could do `$scope.content = ''` inside the cancel function of the modal controller. Just make sure to copy the value out to a different variable if you want to keep it :)

Comment: I have actually done this but is didn't work $scope.content = ''

Comment: Built an example for you using modalInstance.$destroy(). Check out the plunkr here:  http://plnkr.co/KUDSFc

Comment: What can I use in place of hide to kill/destroy the modal. I am using this $scope.closeNewPost = function(index) {
       if (index == 1) {
        alert("close option 1");
    $scope.postModal.hide();
    $scope.content = '';
    $scope.postModal.$destroy();
    
       }

Comment: $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/post.html', {
    id:'1',
    scope: $scope,
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.postModal = modal;

Comment: Ah, ok. Thought we were dealing with AngularUI modals, my bad.  Looks like ionic uses `remove()` to destroy modal instances: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/ instead of `$scope.postModal.hide()`, try `$scope.postModal.remove()`  OR use the event listener pattern in the ionic docs: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/.

Comment: So how can I add it again after removing.

Comment: Re-instantiate from $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(...)

Comment: Example coming... haven't dealt with Ionic enough to write it out cold, but I have a playground app that demonstrates what is going on I think. This looks like a case of scope inheritance confusion.  Here's a link to the sample in the meantime - I'll edit the answer to explain. http://play.ionic.io/app/a33e2f54ec0a

Comment: Ionic example explained in the answer and question upvoted :) Hope this helps!